# How to insert average values of list into the same list?

Tags: python

Given this list:

`[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]`

I want to end up with this list:

`[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32]`

To clarify, I want to transform the first list into this:

`[1, X, 2, X, 4, X, 8, X, 16, X, 32]`

...where `X` is the average between the two preceeding/trailing numbers in the first list. The final list should start with the first value of the first list, and end with the last value of the first list.

I have this as an attempt, but of course this just overwrites the existing list with those average'd numbers. How can I weave them?

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
list_1 = [round((list_1[i] + list_1[i+1])/2) for i in range(len(list_1)-1)]
print(list_1)
```

**UPDATE**

I guess this could work. Maybe there's a better solution?

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
list_2 = [round((list_1[i] + list_1[i+1])/2) for i in range(len(list_1)-1)]
list_1 = sorted(list_1 + list_2)
print(list_1)
```

Comment: So the list is always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is better, but you can consider the following (for python 3.10+ due to `pairwise`):

```py
from itertools import pairwise, chain

lst = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]

means = (round(sum(pair) / 2) for pair in pairwise(lst))
output = [*chain.from_iterable(zip(lst, means)), lst[-1]] # weaving
print(output) # [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32]
```

If `pairwise` is not available, you can use:

```py
means = (round(sum(pair) / 2) for pair in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

Comment: OP is rounding to even in their desired result

Comment: Thanks! Second one works great, should have mentioned I was running 3.7.9. Thanks a lot! Much more pythonic :D

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need the ceiling value of the average because the average of 1 and 2 in your example is 2. Then with simple loop you can do something like this -

```
import math

l = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
r = [l[0]]
for i in range(1,len(l)):
     r.extend([math.ceil((l[i-1]+l[i])/2), l[i]])

print(r)
```

After posting the answer, I saw that you are using `round()`

As @KellyBundy mentioned, the shortened version of the above code would be -

```
l = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
r = l[:1]
for x in l[1:]:
     r += round((r[-1]+x)/2), x

print(r)
```

Comment: [shortened](https://tio.run/##FcnBCoUgEEbh/TzFv1SciLFLhNCTiLvL5QahMhTY01ud3cep1/EveVqq9r5jRRSGZ3wYC0NmxuQTkT5nj0ES/YqiYcsPJaRAeFO4FVrO/DVG4yDJNTt6y2hEVbd8GLW93w)

Comment: @KellyBundy, that's great. Didn't thought of using `r[-1]`. Would you mind if I add that in my answer?

Comment: Feel free to use it.